# Difficult inverse tangent identity

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math

> Prove that:
>
> $$\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 + x} - \sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1 + x} + \sqrt{1-x}} \right) = \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2}\arccos(x), -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \le x \le 1$$

I'd multiply the inside of $\arctan$ by the conjugate of the denominator.

I get:

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1 - 1\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x} \right)$$

But that is still very difficult.

Any HINTS, no solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)$$ $$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})}{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})}\right)$$ $$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+x+1-x-2(\sqrt{1+x})(\sqrt{1-x})}{(\sqrt{1+x})^2-(\sqrt{1-x})^2}\right)$$ $$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2-2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x-(1-x)}\right)$$$$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)$$ Now, let $\color{blue}{x=\sin\theta}$ ($\implies \color{blue}{\theta=\sin^{-1}x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}x}$ $\forall \color{red}{-1\leq x\leq 1}$) & plug it in the above expression we get $$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-(\sin\theta)^2}}{\sin\theta}\right)$$ $$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)$$ $$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\left(1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)$$ $$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}}{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)$$ $$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{\theta}{2}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}x$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}x\right)$$ $$=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}x}$$

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you should explain why $$\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=|\cos\theta|$$ reduces to $$+\cos\theta$$

Comment: @lab: kindly notice if we take negative sign, we get $\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1} x$ which does not satisfy the given equality for example at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. it does not hold true. you may check it out.

Comment: Its not given equality, but a proposition to be verified. If you take $\theta=\arcsin(x)$   by the definition of  Principal value,$$-\dfrac\pi2\le x\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos\theta\ge0$$ and consequently $$|\cos\theta|=+\cos\theta$$

Comment: yes, you are right! but the interval of $x$ is already given in the question which has to be duly satisfied for any proposition obtained.

Comment: We generally see the final results obtained have to duly satisfy the given constraints. that's why I gave it as one of reasons

Answer (score 3):

Let $\dfrac12\arccos x=y\implies x=\cos2y$

and $-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\le x\le1\implies-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\le\cos2y\le1$

Using the definition of Principal values of $\arccos,0\le2y\le\dfrac{3\pi}4\iff0\le y\le\dfrac{3\pi}8 \  \ \ \ (1)$

$\implies\sin y,\cos y\ge0$

$\implies\sqrt{1-x}=\sqrt{1-\cos2y}=+\sqrt2\sin y$

$\implies\sqrt{1+x}=\sqrt{1+\cos2y}=+\sqrt2\cos y$

Now $$\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 + x} - \sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1 + x} + \sqrt{1-x}} \right)=\cdots =\arctan\left[\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4-y\right)\right] $$

which is $\dfrac\pi4-y$

if $-\dfrac\pi2\le\dfrac\pi4-y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\dfrac{3\pi}4\ge y\ge-\dfrac\pi4$ which is satisfied by $(1)$

Answer (score 2):

In the other way round, let

$$\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 + x} - \sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1 + x} + \sqrt{1-x}} \right) =y$$

$\implies -\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\  \ \ \ (1)$ and $\tan y=\dfrac{\sqrt{1 + x} - \sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1 + x} + \sqrt{1-x}}$

Applying [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo),  $$\dfrac{\sqrt{1 + x}}{\sqrt{1 - x}}=\dfrac{1+\tan y}{1-\tan y}$$

Squaring we get,  $$\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}=\dfrac{1+\tan^2y+2\tan y}{1+\tan^2y-2\tan y}$$

Again applying Componendo and dividendo, $$x=\dfrac{2\tan y}{1+\tan^2y}=\sin2y$$

Now $-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\le x\le1\implies-\dfrac\pi4\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2\  \ \ \ (2)$ (using $(1)$)

Finally, $2y=\arcsin x$ if $-\dfrac\pi2\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2$ which is satisfied by $(2)$

$\implies2y=\arcsin x=\dfrac\pi2-\arccos x$